# Block SSH Port in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, firewall, iptables

I want to secure my server by accepting SSH port to my IP address using an internal iptable. I want to know is it good solution ? What happen if I lose my IP address and I will not able to connect SSH ? Do I lose my server ?

Comment: There are several questions here you might want to ask them separately. The title as it stands ("Block SSH Port in Ubuntu") suggests a firewall question. That is easy to answer: yes you should have a firewall; and, as to the implied subsidiary question: yes blocking the standard SSH port might prevent a certain number of attempts on your server. It might be a useful part of your security practices but is not sufficient as security policy though :-)

Answer (score 0):

sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target          prot  opt  source              destination
ACCEPT     all     --    anywhere          anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DROP         tcp    --    anywhere          anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp    --    anywhere          anywhere            tcp dpt:www
DROP         all     --    anywhere          anywhere

Comment: is it kill request ? :D

Comment: Correct.  Change the DROP to ACCEPT to open it.  Then modify the source column if you want to limit who can connect using ssh.

Answer (score 0):

SSH is very useful - if you need it you already know that. If you *don't know* whether you need or not proceed carefully.

The **most basic** SSH policy might include the following:

- Use a non-standard port
- Use password protected keys - not system passwords
- Don't allow root logins
- Use a system service like [DenyHosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/) or firewall rules to block bruteforce attacks and port (OpenBSD's `pf`  has easy to use bruteforce policies).
- Read your server configuration documentation thoroughly and be proactively secure
- If there is a router or firewall appliance between you and your connection try adding timed access restrictions (are you logging in at 3AM ... then why allow it?)
- ... etc. (I will add more items as I remember them)

As to keeping your IP address  ... yes if you don't have a public way to acess your server you will "lose" it. You'll need to use a Dynamic DNS IP service (*e.g.* noip.com) or a script that updates a public email address with your updated IP address when it changes.

If you want to update your internal `iptables` address each time your public address changes then you'll need to re-read your ruleset by adding/modifying the rule to include the new address and then sending a signal to `iptables` to reread its tables or replace the rule for SSH access on that address. With some firewall applications this can be done by sending a signal (`SIGHUP`), with `iptables` you might want to specify the rule to change and then run it as an argument to `iptables -R`.

Check the `iptables` documentation for details about flushing, chain, tables and more fascinating firewall fun.